# CASE query in postgres does not return expected output

Tags: postgresql

In my Postgres database, I am trying to execute the below query:

```
with 
user_details as
    (
        SELECT username
        FROM user_management WHERE username = 'admin'
    ) 
select (case 
when user_details.username is NOT NULL then 'user found'
else
'no user found' end) as username from user_details
```

The above query will return the username and works as expected. But if I pass the username that does not exist in the database, then I expect the CASE query to return 'no user found' but the query does not return anything at all.

But when I tried to execute the below query:

```
select (case 
when (SELECT username
        FROM user_management WHERE username = 'sadmin') is not null  then  'user found'
else
'no user found' end) as username
```

It works as expected and returns the 'no user found'.

Why didn't I get the expected output when using the WITH query in the first case? Is there something with the WITH queries that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you're selecting the output from `user_details` , you're getting `0 rows` , that is the reason you're not seeing any o/p in final result. And in the 2nd query , you're selecting the o/p from sub-query which is null then producing `user not found`. You might run into an error like this

`ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` .
When there is more user having the same username. So your query should look like this

```
select (case 
when exists(SELECT username
        FROM user_management WHERE username = 'sadmin') then  'user found'
else
'no user found' end) as username
```

Comment: if I am getting 0 rows from the user_details, then shouldn't the else part in CASE gets executed?

Comment: The whole `case` statement (both then and else part) is applied to the row. If there are no rows then `case` statement means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the column `username` is unique in the table `user_management`, so the CTE returns either 1 row when the username exists in the table or *nothing* if it does not exist.
Maybe you think that the CTE returns `NULL` in the case where the username does not exist in the table, but it is not.
So if the CTE returns 1 row (the username exists) then your code works fine, but if it returns nothing then your `SELECT` statement that selects `from user_details` will also return nothing, because there are no rows to select from.

Use aggregation so that you will get 1 row in the results even if the user does not exist:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(username), 'no user found') username
FROM user_management 
WHERE username = 'admin'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6fadc248f382c23a0855927cf71d501a).

Comment: I know the other way round, but I wanted to know why did the above query didn't worked.